# Hibernate - fetch data from multple tables using many to one annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I have 3 tables something like:

**car**

```
carid|carname|carPrice|
100|bmw|10L|
200|honda|5L|
..
..
```

**carType**

```
carTypeid|Type|
1|suv|
2|xuv|
3|sedan|
```

**carconfig**

```
carid|carTypeid|
100|3|
200|3|
```

And I have entities for all the 3 tables.

Below I have pasted the code for the joining table **carconfig**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARCONFIG", uniqueConstraints = { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "carId" } )
})
public class Carconfig {

    @Id
    long carId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "carId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Car car;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "carTypeId")
    CarType carType;

    public Carconfig() {
        super();
    }

    public Carconfig(long carId, CarType carType) {
        super();
        this.carType = carType;
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public CarType getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(CarType carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }

    public long getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(long carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

}
```

My problem is :

I want to know how can i get data from both the tables **car** and **carType** and write it to a csv.

Below is the code to get the data.

```
public String downloadcars(CarForm form, Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        try {
            logger.debug("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=car" + ".csv");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-csheck=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            pw = response.getWriter();
            // Get, Write and flush the data.
            pw.println(" Id,Name,Price,Type");
            List<car> carFromDB = Collections.emptyList();



            for (Car car : carFromDB) {             
                pw.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",
             // this is where i need help

            }
            pw.flush();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while downloading car", ex);
            model.addAttribute("failureMsg","Error while downloading cars");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code to `get data`. In question there is not a single line which shows fetching of data. You can use `criteria API` or HQL to fetch data from DB and you can use `Apache POI` for creating csv/excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it using **HQL** with a Join query, like this:

```
List<Object[]> carsWithDetails = session.createQuery(
    "select distinct car.carid, car.carname, car.carPrice, cartype.Type " +
    "from Car  car join car.carType cartype ")
    .list();
```

Then iterate through this `list` of `Object[]` array to extract the car details using an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<Object[]> it = carsWithDetails.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  Object[] car = (Object[]) it.next();
  System.out.println("Car Details:  ");
  System.out.println("Id: "+car[0]);
  System.out.println("Name: "+car[1]);
  System.out.println("Price: "+car[2]);
  System.out.println("Type: "+car[3]);
}
```

And of course change the loop to fit your needs, add the code to write to a `CSV` instead of the `System.out.println` lines.

It will replace this loop:

```
for (Car car : carFromDB) {             
            pw.println(String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",
         // this is where i need help

        }
```

**EDIT:**

If you would like to join all the three tables you just need to add a Join reference `join car.carConfig carConfig`to your query, like this:

```
List<Object[]> carsWithDetails = session.createQuery(
    "select distinct car.carid, car.carname, car.carPrice, cartype.Type " +
    "from Car  car join car.carType cartype join car.carConfig carConfig")
    .list();
```

Comment: could you please explain the HQL you have used. i am a newbie at HQL didnt quite understand it. apologies for the trouble.

Comment: In the following query we use a select for some of the columns whith an alias `car` for `Car` class and `carType` for `CarType` with a `join` between the two tables.

Comment: understood! however can you please show can i join all the 3 tables car cartype and carconfig.

Comment: Thanks a ton. really appreciated !